# weird selection using datagrid in wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm working with WPF and EF. I'm using a Datagrid to show information.

In my viewmodel, I've an ObservableCollection. This collection is the direct source of my DataGrid.
Here is the declaration of my DataGRid :

```
<DataGrid Margin="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionMode="Extended" 
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" 
          AlternationCount="2" 
          Name="DataGridClientSpecs" 
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ClientSpecifications}" 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="500" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Wanted ?" Binding="{Binding Wanted}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product" Binding="{Binding ProductSpecification.ProductType}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Conditionnement" Binding="{Binding ProductSpecification.ConditionnementType}" />
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And I've 2 issues :

- when I try to select a row, it always selects the first row.
- some rows are duplicated.

When I bind the collection to a ListBox, I don't have duplicate rows but the selection is still not working.

Hope someone can help me...

Cheers

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem :-)

It's the fault of Entity Framework !
As it's a list of new items (I mean they doesnt exist in the DB) so their ID's are equal to 0 AND as I'm overwritting the Equals() method for this class and as I'm doing the comparison on the ID, the ID is always 0 so all items of my list are the same :-)

Btw, it's the same with all Control that show a list of items.

Problem Solved ! Hope it will help people.

Cheers
Thomas